# How do I reuse a plot layout in iPython notebook>?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

The code below gives me the image even further below.

```
flowRates=[2,5,10,20,50]
flowRateTol=0.2

#sets the limits for the plot
xRange=(0,700)
yRange=(0,70)

ax=axes()
ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
#ax.set_ylabel('Reaction Force (lbf)')
ax.legend(loc=0)

#set up the second axis
ax.twinx()
ax.set_ylabel('10s Average Flow Rate')

ax.set_xlim(xRange)
ax.set_ylim(yRange)

#shade the acceptable tolerance bands
for flowRate in flowRates:
    rectX=[0,xRange[1],xRange[1],0]
    rectY=[ flowRate*(1-flowRateTol),
            flowRate*(1-flowRateTol),
            flowRate*(1+flowRateTol),
            flowRate*(1+flowRateTol)]
    ax.fill(rectX,rectY,'b', alpha=0.2, edgecolor='r')
```

[image]

However what I'd like to do in my next iPython cell is to actually plot data on the graph. The code I'm using to do so (unsuccessfully is) just has a call to `ax.plot()`, but I can't get a graph to show up with my data.

Any thoughts? My goal is to have a worflow (that I will present) that goes something like this:

1. Look how I import my data!
2. This is how I set up my graph! (show the base plot)
3. This is how I plot all my data! (show the base plot with the data)
4. This is how I filter my data! (do some fancy filtering)
5. This is what the filtered data looks like! (show new data on same base plot)

Comment: you need a `plt.draw()` or `ax.figure.canvas.draw()` to re-render the axes.  You should capture the second axes as `ax2 = ax.twinx()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest packaging different ideas into functions. E.g

1. This is how I import data:

   def Import_Data(file_name,...):
       # Stuff to import data
       return data
2. This is how I plot my data:
   def Plot(data..)

Plotting just the base plot seems like a special case that you may do once, but if you really want to be able to show this, and minimise the amount of repeated code just allow `data=None` to ignore errors and not plot anything.

The great thing about splitting code up like this is that it is easy to make changes to just one function, provided then just worry about inputs and outputs. For instance to filter you can either add a filter paramateter to the `plot` function, or create new filtered data that is plotted in the same way!

Comment: It sort of felt like I was having a structural problem, not a programming problem. Your solution worked well. Thank you.